# Table row not expanding to full width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table and when I set the table to a width of 100% and the table rows to a width pf 100% nothing happens or changes to the width.

```css
.Table-Normal {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

.Table-Normal thead tr {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Table-Normal tr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 100%;
}

.Table-Normal tr td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.Table-Normal tbody tr:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<table id="top-leader" class="Table-Normal">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Position</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Kills</td>
      <td>Deaths</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>16 Kills</td>
      <td>0 Deaths</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>13 Kils</td>
      <td>1 Death</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Bob Smith</td>
      <td>11 Kills</td>
      <td>0 Deaths</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Remove `display: block` in `.Table-Normal`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37ZRV/1/)

```
.Table-Normal {
    position: relative;
    //display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: removing display block property causes the table no scrolling x-axis anymore

Comment: or use "display: table;"

Answer (score 34):

By specifying `display: block` you've overriding the default value from the browser stylesheet for the `table` element: `display: table`. Removing `display: block` or replacing it with `display: table` fixes this.

Comment: solved my problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As people have mentioned you have to remove `display:block;` for this to work. If you need to keep scrolling functionality wrap the table inside a div and set overflow rules on that

```
<div class = "table-container">
   <table>...</table>
</div>

.table-container{
   height:100px
   width:100px
   overflow-x:scroll;
   
   table{
      display: table;
      width:100%;
   }
}
```

Comment: after trying out a lot of options for this problem. this is what worked for me. and my situation is kinda strange as well, cause i need the thead to stick at the top, but having a warpper still worked. thx