# Table not stretching out to the full width of the enclosing body

Tags: html, css, html-table, stretch

I have a simple table that doesn't stretch out to the full width of the body. I've tried setting margins and padding to 0 everywhere, and setting width=100% where appropriate.

Here is the HTML/CSS in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fbCgk/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <table class="myTable">
        <tr>
            <button type='submit' id="button1">Button1</button>
            <button type='submit' id="button2">Button2</button>
            <form id="myForm">
                <input id="userInput" type="text"/>
            </form>
       </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.myTable {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  margin: 5px; 
}

form {
  margin: 5px;
}

.myTable {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.controls tr td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I tried referring to what was posted here: [Table Row Not Expanding To Full Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715927/table-row-not-expanding-to-full-width), but testing out the different properties (including position: relative) didn't fix the issue. What am I missing?

Comment: Try adding 1px solid borders to each part of the table in different colors - that can help troubleshoot tables.

Comment: Your JsFiddle doesn't match the code you gave us... And if you want your above code to work, then you might want to add some `td` tags like so: http://jsfiddle.net/fbCgk/69/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You forgot to add `td` inside `tr`
and for inline  form you have to add -

```
display: inline-block;
```

for form id  `#myForm`

```
<body>
     <table class="myTable">
          <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type='submit' id="button1">Button1</button>
                    <button type='submit' id="button2">Button2</button>
                    <form id="myForm">
                        <input id="userInput" type="text"/>
                    </form>
                </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
</body>


.myTable {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

button {
    margin: 5px; 
}

form {
    margin: 5px;
}

.myTable {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.controls tr td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#myForm{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css and check table row streched for full width:

```
.myTable  tr
{
    background: green;
}
```